# Metadata unavailable in controller's onExit event (?)

Tags: sapui5

Trying to use some code within the onExit function of my detail controller in order to call a function import that will "release" my record when user presses the top home launchpad button from there. While everything seems to be available at the time (check snapshot after the error), I call the function import, I get the following error:

```html
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property '_getFunctionImportMetadata' of undefined
    at eval (eval at evalModuleStr (jquery.sap.global-dbg.js:3315), <anonymous>:2607:463)
    at eval (eval at evalModuleStr (jquery.sap.global-dbg.js:3315), <anonymous>:2603:192)
(anonymous) @ VM32:2607
(anonymous) @ VM32:2603
Promise.then (async)  
r._processRequest @ VM32:2603
r.callFunction @ VM32:2607
(anonymous) @ Object.controller.js?eval:205
onExit @ Object.controller.js?eval:202
a.fireEvent @ EventProvider-dbg.js:229
a.fireEvent @ Element-dbg.js:593
(anonymous) @ ManagedObjectMetadata-dbg.js:426
c.exit @ VM32:917
f.exit @ VM32:954
h.destroy @ ManagedObject-dbg.js:2270
a.destroy @ Element-dbg.js:555
b.destroy @ Control-dbg.js:602
f.destroy @ VM32:960
destroy @ VM32:1111
c._destroyCreatedInstances @ VM32:531
c.destroy @ VM32:530
destroy @ Component.js?eval:302
s @ VM32:86
d.exit @ VM32:91
h.destroy @ ManagedObject-dbg.js:2270
a.destroy @ Element-dbg.js:555
b.destroy @ Control-dbg.js:602
h.destroyAggregation @ ManagedObject-dbg.js:1974
j @ VM33:1326
exit @ VM33:1343
A.exit @ VM33:1861
h.destroy @ ManagedObject-dbg.js:2270
a.destroy @ Element-dbg.js:555
b.destroy @ Control-dbg.js:602
onAfterNavigate @ VM33:1861
p @ jquery-dbg.js:497
a.fireEvent @ EventProvider-dbg.js:229
a.fireEvent @ Element-dbg.js:593
(anonymous) @ ManagedObjectMetadata-dbg.js:426
(anonymous) @ VM33:2722
sap.ushell.ui.launchpad.ViewPortContainer._handleViewPortTransition @ VM33:2730
sap.ushell.ui.launchpad.ViewPortContainer._setCurrentlyDisplayedControl @ VM33:2724
sap.ushell.ui.launchpad.ViewPortContainer.navTo @ VM33:2722
_handleEmbeddedNavMode @ VM33:1861
(anonymous) @ VM33:1861
p @ jquery-dbg.js:3187
add @ jquery-dbg.js:3246
navigate @ VM33:1861
_initiateApplication @ VM33:1861
(anonymous) @ VM33:1861
p @ jquery-dbg.js:3187
add @ jquery-dbg.js:3246
doHashChange @ VM33:1861
p @ jquery-dbg.js:497
sap.ushell.services.ShellNavigationHashChanger.treatHashChanged @ VM33:2188
execute @ VM32:3214
dispatch @ VM32:3217
dispatch @ VM32:3216
(anonymous) @ VM32:3204
i @ VM32:3204
```

My model seems to be still in place as debugger suggests (see below) and this code (supposed to become a common function, copied here for testing purposes) is running just fine when I'm using the back button to navigate to my main view. Of course, back end method doesn't get called. Code attached at the end. Any ideas?

[image]

```js
  onExit: function() {
   var oParamModel = this.getView().getModel("Global");
   var oModel = this.getView().getModel();
   if (oParamModel.getProperty("/RecordUnlocked") === true) {
    var unlockOnExit = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
     oParamModel.setProperty("/RecordUnlocked", true);
     var sAgreement = oParamModel.getProperty("/AgreementID");
     oModel.callFunction("/Agreement_Unlock", {
      method: 'GET',
      urlParameters: {
       "Agreement_Code": sAgreement
      },
      success: function(oData, response) {
       resolve(oData);
      },
      error: function(oError) {}
     });
    });
    
    var callFetch = function () {
        unlockOnExit
            .then(function (fulfilled) {
            })          
            .catch(function (error) {
 
            });
    };
    
    callFetch(); 
   }
  },
```

Comment: where are you executing '_getFunctionImportMetadata'? I think your `this` pointer is undefined where you are calling the function `_getFunctionImportMetadata`

Comment: @KristoffDT: I don't call it explicitly, it's called by the framework underneath (VM31:2607). Furthermore, "this.getModel()" that is assigned to my var points to the right path as debugger suggests. Am I missing anything here? (quite possible)

Comment: @KristoffDT: Correction, VM32:2607

Comment: hmm correct, my bad I was too quick in my answer. Too be honest I have never done something similar to what you are trying here :/